# In express.js is there a way to handle both ajax form submitions and browser post submits?

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I have a contact form on my site built with express.js (4.0). I'm wondering how to handle the situation where my user has JavaScript Disabled.

If the end of my routing function says:

```
res.render('contact.jade', {
  title: 'Thanks for reaching out!',
  errors: errors,
  now: new Date().getFullYear()
});
```

Will this handle AJAX as well as a normal form submission? Is there a better way to handle it? (Does this hamper performance for either?)

Comment: If it returns a full html page, and your ajax properly extracts specific content from it to insert into the page, yes. However, i would argue that the likelihood of anyone using said contact form with javascript disabled is very slim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `req.xhr` when using express, which is set to true if the request has the `X-Requested-With` header set to `XMLHttpRequest`, which is done by most frameworks or can be done manually.

Example:

```
if (req.xhr) {
    res.json(errors);
} else {
    res.render('contact.jade', {
        title: 'Thanks for reaching out!',
        errors: errors,
        now: new Date().getFullYear()
    });
}
```